# How can I group by rows and columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

I can not find any question/answer that could help me to get close to my goal. I have the following table [check code on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35cff/7).

```
SITENAME RTYPE SEASON  CTRSTAT  CTRTYPE UNITS  STARTDATE  WKTYPE    INVSTAT
 site1    T2B    P     null      null    92      null     FRSA_P    Unsold
 site1    T2B    Pre   null      null    36      null     FRSA_P    Unsold
 site1    T2B    PRI   null      null    173     null     FRSA_P    Unsold
 site1    T2B    SPE   null      null    56      null     FRSA_P    Unsold
 site1    T2B    P    Complete   FRSA    2     2013-01-01 FRSA_P    Sold
 site1    T2B    Pre  Complete   FRSA    2     2013-01-01 FRSA_P    Sold
 site1    T2B    PRI  Complete   FRSA    2     2013-01-01 FRSA_P    Sold
 site1    T2B    P    Complete   FRSA    1     2013-03-05 FRSA_P    Sold
 site1    T2B    P    Complete   FRSA    3     2014-01-01 FRSA_P    Sold
 site1    T2B    Pre  Complete   FRSA    4     2014-01-01 FRSA_P    Sold
 site1    T3B    P     null      null    69      null     FRSA_P    Unsold
 site1    T3B    Pre   null      null    26      null     FRSA_P    Unsold
 site1    T3B    PRI   null      null    125     null     FRSA_P    Unsold
 site1    T3B    SPE   null      null    40      null     FRSA_P    Unsold
 site1    T3B    Pre  Complete   FRSA    2     2013-01-01 FRSA_P    Sold
 site1    T3B    P    Complete   FRSA    1     2014-01-01 FRSA_P    Sold
 site1    T3B    Pre  Complete   FRSA    2     2014-01-01 FRSA_P    Sold
```

Then somehow get to a report like the one on the following picture. If the InvStatus is unsold, the report should return *Unsold*, otherwise the CTRSTAT.

[image: Result after grouping by columns and rows with totals]

Please do not pay attention to the totals and grand total, the image is from an excel using other data. Is just to have sample of the needed result.

**EDIT:** The dates columns correspond to a full year so for example the one with `2013-03-05` belongs to the `01/01/2013` column. In case of null date then they will go to the last year displayed, on this case `01/01/2014` but could be 2015 o whatever period is the last displayed.

I have tried several different approaches, using `GROUP BY` together with `GROUPING` and `SETS` of various types but none worked. `CUBE` and `ROLLUP` are not useful or at least I have not managed to get the correct result. Maybe just is not possible, at least not on an easy way.

Here is a sample of one of the many queries I have tried, trying to twist it to get something like the report, but still nothing close.

```
SELECT
       sitename, rtype, season, ctrstat, ctrtype, SUM(units)
      ,startdate, invstat
  FROM tt
 GROUP BY
GROUPING SETS ((sitename,InvStat,ctrstat)
               ,(RType,ctrtype,season,startdate)
               ,()
              )
```

**EDIT:** Maybe should be better using the SSRS for this task?

Comment: Interesting problem. It's not easy, but it's possible. Before you start grouping, you'll have to do some pivoting first to extract columns you need. If I get some free time in the next few hours, I'll try to give you some queries, but can't promise.

Comment: Few questions: How does your startdate translate to which columns data belong? 2013 or 2014? Specially for unsold where it's NULL? Where does 2013-03-05 goes? Can you provide expected results based on this exact data you have posted?

Comment: Thanks @NenadZivkovic, check the new edit. On some point I thought about pivoting but I didn't even knew how to approach the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention in your edit I think doing this i SSRS is the way to go. You can use a matrix to easily create the report you are looking for. By using the data given in your SQL fiddle you can quickly get something as shown below.

Edit: Added total values
[image]

[image]

Comment: Whoaa! Nicely done. I'm newbie using SSRSm can you point out some link where I could find something like this? Not just a tutorial, as it will cover basic stuff that I already aware of.

Comment: This report is created by using grouping on the different fields. This msdn page is a good introduction to grouping and adding totals. Which is basicly what you're after: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx

Comment: Great, I'm on my way to do it, the columns groups are a bit fustrating, but think I will have it done soon. Thanks again, this was the faster way as I can reuse the table the stored procedure returns for other reports without the need of modifying it.

Comment: Groups is not the most intuitive thing to work with always, but once you get the hang of it, groups are really effective! Good luck!

Comment: I already have the report on production, user (and me) is satisfied and I've learned something new, thanks @Nighty_ and SO as always

Answer (score 1):

While SSRS probably is a better option, here is how it can be done with SQL query. At the end, combining the two might be the best solution.

```
WITH CTE_Pivot AS 
(
    SELECT
         sitename
        ,rtype
        ,season
        ,CASE WHEN invstat = 'Sold' AND ctrStat = 'Complete' AND YEAR(startdate)=2013 THEN units ELSE 0 END AS Complete2013
        ,CASE WHEN invstat = 'Sold' AND ctrStat = 'Complete' AND (YEAR(startdate)=2014 OR startdate IS NULL) THEN units ELSE 0 END AS Complete2014
        ,CASE WHEN invstat = 'Unsold' AND YEAR(startdate)=2013 THEN units ELSE 0 END AS Unsold2013
        ,CASE WHEN invstat = 'Unsold' AND (YEAR(startdate)=2014 OR startdate IS NULL) THEN units ELSE 0 END AS Unsold2014
        ,units AS Total
    FROM tt 
)
SELECT sitename,rtype,season
    ,SUM(Complete2013) AS Complete2013
    ,SUM(Complete2014) AS Complete2014
    ,SUM(Unsold2013) AS Unsold2013
    ,SUM(Unsold2014) AS Unsold2014
    ,SUM(Total) AS GrandTotal
FROM CTE_Pivot
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((sitename,rtype,season),(sitename,rtype),sitename)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35cff/9)**

First part is to pivot your columns. This is rather simple way, without using `PIVOT` function, but declaring conditions for each column in `CASE` statement. It assumes you have a fixed number of possible values (and columns) which might not be perfect, but creating [dynamic columns require dynamic SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/) which would bring this query to whole new level of complexity.

After all in this case, I don't really think you'll have much different values for CTRSTAT and I guess you know upfront all possible values. Years are a bit more problematic, but still I guess there aren't that many. You can maybe go with "THIS Year, LAST Year, NEXT Year" to make it somewhat more adaptable for future.

Second part of query is just grouping by using simple grouping sets. ROLLUP would be same as this.

Comment: Tested, also working, you have my upvote. I preferred to use the answer given by @Nighty_ as this way I can reuse the stored procedure for other reports. I will save this tsql sample for other needs, thanks again.